# Read a file from Tomcat webapps on different Tomcats

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, csv

Consider the following:
I got a csv-file. This file is stored in the tomcat wepapps directory. The path to this directory is dependent of the computer used. There are users that use different locations for their Tomcats and use different names. I want to achieve the following.

Via Spring i did the following:
I got an action which imports some data from the csv to the database.

```
<bean id="setCsvPathAction" class="custom.action.importcsv.SetCsvPathAction">
   <property name="csvPath" value="C:/temp/test.csv"/>
</bean>
```

This works fine for me. To make this path more configurable for others i got a system.properties file. With this file you can easily overrite properties:

```
setCsvPathAction.csvPath=#{tomcat_home}/webapps/test.csv
```

That is what i want. I want the path to be on the Tomcat webapps directory. The above doesn't work. Do you have any hint how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Most people who use tomcat would have set CATALINA_HOME environment variable. You can query this environment variable and retrieve value.

```
String tomcat_home = System.getenv("CATALINA_HOME");
if(tomcat_home){
    setCsvPathAction.csvPath=tomcat_home+"/webapps/test.csv"
}
```

**Note: There's no guarantee that this environment variable is set on every system using tomcat**

More on getenv() - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28%29

Comment: I want to set the path in a property of a bean. I can't write any code.

Comment: Yes you can. You are already using a property file. You can programmatically add to a property file. Do this when you app is initialized.

Comment: I don't think you two understand me the right way. I will deliver a product to a costumer. I don't want him to set the path to his webapps folder. That's why i do this for him and write the path in the properties file. If he does want to change the path, he just needs to configure it in the .properties file. That's why i can't set it programmatically. If i could just write something like: "setCsvPathAction.csvPath=#{tomcat_home}/webapps/test.csv" in the .properties file it would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If it is going to be in the web apps folder you could also just use the class loader to get the local path so you do not have to configure anything.

someObject.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("path/refferenced/to/app/root/");

Comment: I want to set the path in a property of a bean. I can't write any code.

Comment: That is what I am saying.  You would not need to set anything this way.  It is one less thing for you to have to configure.  Since from the example it is your bean you can just change it to get the path location from the ClassLoader and not have to configure it.

Comment: I think i understood what you meant. I did the following: this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/" + m_csvPath)); where m_csvPath is the name of the csvFile, which is set via SpringInjection. Sadly i am getting a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the .properties file was: ${catalina.home}
Next i need a FileInputStream independent of the system environment. I tried the following:

```
public class environmentTest {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getenv("CATALINA_BASE"));
    }

}
```

null gets printed on the console.

The class Person contains the name of the jpg file. This file is located at the webapps folder. I want the path to be independent of the computer used. I tried the following:

```
File file = new File(System.getenv("CATALINA_HOME") + "/webapps/" + person.getPhoto());
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Sadly this doesn't work because, as unekwu said, this environment variable is not set on all systems. Do you have any idea what i can do in this situation?